# Problem providing service key ( serviceAccountKey ) to Camel Google PubSub example

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-camel, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

From `https://github.com/apache/camel-examples.git` in `examples/google/google-pubsub` I have edited `src/main/resources/application.properties` to try the example against my new Google Cloud setup. I'm sure I have the `topicName` and `subscriptionName` correct but I'm not quite sure what to provide for `serviceAccountKey`.

I've tried the identifier, the file path, etc .. what is the correct way to furnish this example with the service key I created on Google Cloud, please?

Answer (score 0):

The [application.properties](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/main/examples/google/google-pubsub/src/main/resources/application.properties) file indicates:

```
serviceAccountKey=base64:xxxx
```

So you need to provide the base64 encrypted version of your service account key JSON file.  You can do this with: `cat YOUR_CREDENTIALS.json | base64`.  The output should be a very long string, which you replace the `xxxx` with.

EDIT: the command just base64 encodes the string you pass to it.  You can try to decrypt the string again by doing `echo 'ENCRYPTED_STRING' | base64 --decode`

Comment: I tried that Glen, and it doesn't seem to work. Base64 the json, reduce it to a one-line string, The example just sits there. I check metrics on Google Cloud and there is no activity.

Comment: I tried to run the example on my own to see, but I'm getting `mvn compile` and `mvn camel:run` errors that has to do with dependencies/packages.  Unfortunately I don't know maven, so I don't know how to make it work :(